# Python/Django Trying to continually reference foreign keys in multiple classes and be able to print out information from views

Tags: python, django

I know how to reference a single foreign key but when it comes to a foreign key inside another foreign key, I'm lost. I can't think of the correct logic to make this work, which makes me think there's a special logic that applies to this.

What I've tried:

```
    b2=[]
    league = League.objects.get(name='International Collegiate Baseball Conference')
    team = league.teams.all()
    for b in team.curr_players.all():
       b2.append(b.first_name + b.last_name)
```

From my models:

```
class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, related_name="teams")

class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    curr_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="curr_players")
    all_teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, related_name="all_players")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, i had to do a for loop to iterate through what i was receiving from league.teams.all() - which was a team object and then set the iterations equal to a variable and set another iteration equal to variable.related_name.all()

```
b2=[]
league = League.objects.get(name='International Collegiate Baseball Conference')
team = league.teams.all()
for a in team:
    players = a
    for b in players.curr_players.all():
        b2.append(b.first_name + b.last_name)
```